# posting data with backbone form post

Tags: backbone.js

i am unable to get form post to work.  below is snippet for form view with event handling but I am unable to see form data printed in console from getFormData.  I am not sure if this is right approach to form handling but was just trying it out reading stuff from net.

```
define(['backbone', 'handlebars', 'jquery', 'events', 'models/article'], function(Backbone, Handlebars, $, Events, Article) {



var ArticleFormView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "submit": "createArticle"
  },
  tagName: "form",
  id: "article-form",
  className: "articleform",
  initialize: function() {
    this.model = new Article();
    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {
    var template = $("#createarticletemplate").html();
    console.log("template=" + template);
    var compiled = Handlebars.compile(template);
    var html = compiled(this.model.attributes);//passed when we do new View()
    console.log("compiled template=" + template);
    this.$el.html(html);
    return this;
  },
  createArticle: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("createArticle event happened" + $(this.el).parent().html());
    var data = this.getFormData( $(this.el).parent() );
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

   this.model.save(data, {
     success: function(model, response, options) {
     console.log("create article success");
     Events.trigger("router:navigate", "#");
   },
   error: function(model, response, options) {
     return console.log("create article failure:" + response.responseText);
   }
 });

  },
  //Auxiliar function
   getFormData: function(form) {
     console.log(form);
     var unindexed_array = form.serializeArray();
     console.log(unindexed_array.length);
     var indexed_array = {};

     $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
       console.log("array:" + n);
            indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
     });

     return indexed_array;
   },
}); //artifleformview

  return ArticleFormView;
});
```

snippet of routes/index.js

```
exports.articles.createone = function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  //res.json(req.body);
  db.articles.insert(req.body);
}
```

article.js model:

```
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) {
  var Article = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: "/article",
  idAttribute: "_id"
});
  return Article;
});
```

### console log:

```
createArticle event happened<form id="article-form" class="articleform"><label>title </label><input type="text" name="title"><p></p><label>body </label><input type="text" name="body"><p></p><label>category </label><input type="text" name="category"><p></p><input type="submit" value="create article"></form> articleform.js:27
[div.form, prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: form#article-form.articleform, jquery: "1.11.1", constructor: function, selector: ""…]
 articleform.js:44
0 articleform.js:46
{} articleform.js:29
create article success articleform.js:33
index called on router
```

Adding createArticle error log:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/article net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE jquery.js:4
send jquery.js:4
m.extend.ajax jquery.js:4
e.ajax backbone.js:1
e.sync backbone.js:1
i.extend.sync backbone.js:1
i.extend.save backbone.js:1
Backbone.View.extend.createArticle articleform.js:33
m.event.dispatch jquery.js:3
r.handle
```

If some one wants more code let me know I can put all code here but its too many files so better would be some link I attach if needed.

Above log for error prints in console thought the article is getting persisted fine.

Regards,

Miten.

Comment: this question is very confusing.  "unable to see form data" ... ok where?  cant see it visually where the user typed it?  cant see it your getFormData method?  cant see it when it should be sent to the server?  also, it looks like the exports.articles.createOne snippet is nodejs code?  yeah?  that would certainly be a useful thing to call out if you suddenly switch platforms in between code snippets.    where is the nodejs code that returns a response to the client?  lastly, you  posted logging data but its not clear what actually writes those log messages so they arent super helpful.

Comment: I understand but did not want to add all files here as then it seems I added every thing here.  I am not sure if i can add the zip file here if so let me know and I can add it.  Basically I showed the articleform.js which is want is used to handle form submit and then showed the logs as much I felt relevant.

Comment: you didnt answer any of my questions, none of them require posting a zip file, just clarifications.  the problem is that you nodejs method isn't returning a response to the client so the service call eventually times out and is handled as a failure

Comment: I am understanding things myself.  First I was not getting getFormData invoked which Ravi helped answer.  Then I saw that form submit was persisting the article but then success was not getting invoked.  You point out that createArticle (nodejs method) is not returning any response.  I was under impression that success would get called and it would return user to index page but seems error is called and there is no response as you point out.  I will check on it as you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to replace

```
var data = this.getFormData( $(this.el).parent() );
```

with

```
var data = this.getFormData(this.$('form'));
```

or

```
var data = this.getFormData(this.$el.closest('form'));
```

Comment: closest form reply work but the model success is not getting called.

Comment: if success is not getting called, then error should get called, have a debugger is both places and check what is the error you getting, some thing could be wrong on server API

Comment: After quite delay the error function was called indeed but the article is getting persisted fine since if I go to list the articles its showing up.  When you say DEBUG I only know to add console.log.  did you mean some debugger is there on node.js side apart from I am running it via monitor the app.js.  I have added logs to original message.

Comment: Then it's not related Backbone View, when I said debugger, I meant `debugger` statement, which will stop execution of javascript at that point. and let you analyse arguments and stack. If error is getting called, it's issue on the server side (may be node.js).

Comment: sorry could not get what you mean by "Then it's not related Backbone View".  you mean the ArticleForm is not backbone view ?

Comment: I meant the issue is not because of Backbone, problem could be with the server responding for your save call

Comment: http://imagebin.ca/v/1UxnP36KxSyt it shows now what error I get.  I tried to amend code to return console.log in error function but seems did not improve any thing.

Comment: basically response is empty, looks like server handling the request but not returning any thing, I think there could be some server error because of which server couldn't create the article and returning empty response. Not sure what is happening on server side

Comment: server is creating article.  Also error function is called but does not have any message.